# nullpointerexception error removal of node

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I'm stuck at this one road and it's really beginning to frustrate me. I think I have everything working properly but this one method.

When I remove a Node from my LL I get a null pointer exception on the next attempt ,and I can't figure out what.

```
public void timeSlice(int cpuTime){
    for(Node curr=head; curr.getNext()!=head; curr=curr.getNext()){
        curr.time=curr.time-cpuTime;
        System.out.print("<" + curr.pid + ", " + curr.time +">" + " ");
        //if the time remaining <= 0 then remove the node
        if(curr.time<=0){
            System.out.println("\nProcess " + curr.pid + " has finished, and is now being terminated");
            remove(curr);
        }
    }
}//end timeSlice
```

It occurs after the removal and restarting of the method. I think it's because I just removed the curr but I'm not 100% sure.

```
public void remove(Node node){
    if(size == 0){
        return; 
    }
    else if(size == 1){
        removeFirst();
    }
    else{
        Node curr;
        for(curr=head; curr.getNext()!=node; curr=curr.getNext()){
        ;
        }
        curr.setNext(curr.getNext().getNext());
        node.setNext(null);
    }
        size --;
}//end remove
```

Now the current test is that it will remove the second to last node

Comment: What is the source of your remove() method?

Comment: @Catherine the remove is up

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because head == null. Next time post the error stack trace and you'll have a higher chance of getting a more exact answer.

If head is null, you're setting curr to null, then calling the "getNext()" method on null, which will result in a nullPointerException. At least, that's my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

Once `remove()` is called in `timeSlice()`, `curr` variable in `timeSlice()` is pointing to the removed node and `curr.getNext()` returns `null` which causes `NullPointerException`.

As @Catherine suggested, you should keep a reference to the previous node and make its usage cleaner with a dummy node at the head of the list. (Sorry, I don't have enough rep to vote up.)

```
// head.getNext() == head
Node head = new Node();

public void timeSlice(int cpuTime) {
    Node prev = head; // A dummy at head.
    Node curr = prev.getNext();
    for ( ; curr != head; prev = curr, curr = curr.getNext()) {
        // ...
        if (/* remove? */) {
            removeNext(prev);
            curr = prev;
        }
    }
}

public void removeNext(Node node) {
    node.setNext(node.getNext().getNext());
}
```

Comment: i'm supposed to be using a singly linked list, i'm using another node to break the link between the nodes

Comment: As @Catherine suggested, you'd better keep the previous node and switch it with `curr` after `remove()` returns. Otherwise, removing a node without a pointer to its previous one can't be natural in a singly-linked list.

Answer (score 0):

After you call `remove` on `curr`, `curr`'s `getNext()` will return `null`.  Then you go into the next iteration of your loop with a `null` value for `curr`.

You should also be checking for `null` even once you fix that. Why go into the loop if your node is null?

Comment: How do I set it so that it won't be null?

Comment: Not calling `setNext(null)` in your `remove` call would be one way, since that's where you're getting the next node in your loop, but that's not very clean. I'm not sure that there's a great way of doing what you're doing cleanly though. Ideally if you're setting `curr`'s next to `null` you would set `curr` to its previous node before removal so the next iteration of your loop isn't screwed up. Maybe keep around the previous node? You could also have your `remove` method return the removed node's previous node.

Comment: Also, that suggestion would not work out if you're removing the head. Maybe a dummy node as the head could solve that issue.